# Qual software usar para gerar uma imagem de um grafo gigante?

Tags: c++, grafo

Tenho um programa em c++, feito com a representação de grafos com lista de adjacência, porém, existem mais de 2 milhões de nós nele.
Existe algum software que tenha um formato de texto, que eu possa gerar do meu programa, e importar nesse software para gerar uma imagem?

Comment: Eu surgiria OpenGL com WxWidgets, mas precisaria ter um nível de programação avançado e muito tempo

Answer (score 1):

Faça seu software gerar um arquiovo no padrão [`graphviz`](https://www.graphviz.org/).
É um padrão "de facto" e vários softwares conseguirão abrí-lo.

Alguns links que podem ser úteis:

Geral:

- http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html
- http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html
- https://graphs.grevian.org/example

C++ + Graphviz:

- http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/graphviz-and-c/184402049
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html